# ffmpeg RTSP streams to RGB24 using GPU

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I have successfully output RTSP stream to RGB24 pipe but I notice the CPU usage is still high (20-45%) despite using `-hwaccel cuvid` and `-vcodec h264_cuvid` (without hardware acceleration it can go up to 100-300%; based on "top" command on Linux).

The current code I am using is:

```
ffmpeg
.input(*rtsp_add*, rtsp_transport='tcp', fflags='nobuffer', flags='low_delay', hwaccel='cuvid', vcodec='h264_cuvid', vsync=0)
.output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
.run_async(quiet=False, pipe_stdout=True)
```

The moment i use -vcodec h264_nvenc, I get a bunch of error as I believe it is incompatible with RGB24. Using the command "ffmpeg -pix_fmts", I notice almost nothing falls under the "Hardware accelerated format". I do not mind working in YUV420p, YUV444p, RGB24 etc... Does this mean that I am unable to output images into the pipe if I choose to use hardware encoding?

I would prefer to write the output to a pipe as compared to writing it to a physical file and reading it again to manipulate the data for performance. The option to output to a in-memory JPG or PNG is also good.

Comment: Not sure about the Python syntax, but in commandline, you have to download the texture from the GPU in a pix_fmt that is both supported by the GPU and CPU. If you select cuvid decoder, then the output format will probably be `cuda`, which is GPU-only format. With nvidia cards, the best option seems to be the `nv12` format. Once the frame is downloaded in `nv12` to CPU, you can convert it to any other format of your liking. The commandline part achieving this would be `-vf "hwdownload,format=nv12" -pix_fmt rgb24` as options before the output file.